# SQL Server Differential Backup Size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

The setup is SQL Server 2008 R2:

- Full Backup - Weekly  ~1.1TB
- Differential - Every 4 hours ~66GB
- Transactional - Every hour

What I want to know is why is the very first differential backup about 60GB, when a few transactions have taken place?

I get that 'differential' acts in an aggregating way, but shouldn't the first differential be substantially smaller than the last differential in between full backups?

There is a maintenance job that optimizes indexes. It runs after the first differential backup after weekly full.

Comment: One thing you might try is to set up a SQL Agent job to run every minute or so and capture the results of `select sum(modified_extent_page_count) from sys.dm_db_file_space_usage` for the database in question.  This might point you to the timeframe where the number of modified pages since the last full dramatically increases.

Comment: Unfortunately these new columns are available in 2017 and onwards

Comment: Are all of your differentials approximately that size?  I would look for any other maintenance jobs or dataloads/ETL that run in that timeframe.  You could always increase the frequency of the differentials or look at the log backups to get a better estimate of when it happens.